# Keycloak v21.0.1 Custom changes in JS folder are not reflected when compiled (PUT to POST change)

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, maven, keycloak

Im building Keycloak from source with some of my own customizations in place, for eg: changing PUT method to POST in a few apis, as PUT requests are blocked in my organzation.

i made the following changes in this file *keycloak/js/libs/keycloak-admin-client/src/resources/users.js*

```
/**
   * reset password
   */
  public resetPassword = this.makeRequest<
    { id: string; credential: CredentialRepresentation },
    void
  >({
    method: "POST", // changed, from PUT to POST
    path: "/{id}/reset-password",
    urlParamKeys: ["id"],
    payloadKey: "credential",
  });
```

and build the project using this command.

`mvn -X -pl quarkus/dist -am -DskipTests clean install`

but checking in the web browser, under sources, the method still shows as PUT, changes are not reflected when building it, as i missing something?

[image]

i even cleaned using npm clean, deleted node_modules folder and ran npm install and npm build, then mvn build.
is there a different way to build this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not post images of text, but the text directly.